# Scala SBT Playframework always showing welcome page

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0

When I go to sbt and type the command "start" it shows me what it should show me, a simple page with a simple message.

But when I go to sbt and type the command "run", it shows me a welcome screen. The routing files shows the default page getting sent to the Application controller and the index function. The index function calls index.scala.html.

Why do I keep getting the welcome screen when choosing "run"? I can't get rid of the welcome page.

Answer (score 8):

Everything is all right, welcome screen is always displayed on the freshly created application in `development mode`. The dev mode is called with `run` command (in oposite to `production mode` started with `start` command).

As you discovered - to get rid of this you just need replace the default content of the `index.scala.html` view - after that, this is **absolutely your** view with no more welcomes.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure why I always got the welcome screen, but changing the view in the controller solved the problem.